# Would this potential Saint Petersburg house rule work?

Tags: house-rules, saint-petersburg

A friend mentioned a possible easy tweak of the Saint Petersburg rules: just pay out the buildings once again at the end of the game (perhaps disallowing observatory/debtor's prison except for taking the 1 VP).

This has two possible advantages:

1. It could enable a viable blue-heavy strategy to compete with the as-many-aristocrats-kinds-as-possible strategy.
2. The trading card phase at the end would actually matter for blues as well as aristocrats.

Can anyone shoot holes in the idea?  I'm curious for people to try this out and report how it goes.

Comment: Could this possibly be reformatted into a question?  Or is this intended to just have "Yes this works", "No it doesn't" answers?

Comment: Reformatted a bit, but that's basically what I was going for, yes.

Comment: Have you tried this house rule?  I'm a little put-off by you asking for other folks to try it out and report back if you haven't gone through that effort yourself.

Comment: Pat, wow.  I haven't had a chance to play, but not for lack of effort or desire.  There's a presumption that people who would try it out would, well, want to try it out!  The implication of your statement is that I should withhold the idea until I've tried it, because I am somehow doing damage by presenting it untested.  If you are someone who doesn't like testing house rules, then obviously that addendum is not for you.

Comment: Voting to close because no experience with the house rule has been demonstrated [per this meta question](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/535/1140). A better version would be "A problem we've had with Saint Petersburg is X; using Y house rule seems to have helped. Is there a side effect we're missing?"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why this would *fail* to work, but it would change the strategy.  I'll give it a go next time I play, if I can persuade the other players to try it.